# How to correctly fix row spacing in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create some small widgets with flutter as a beginners-task. However, I am stuck at fixing the spacing between single elements within rows. For reference, this is how it currently looks: [image]

(I removed the padding) I want the text to be aligned so the space is seperated evenly, but neither MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly nor TextAlign.start help.
In my head, it would look more like this (incoming paint skill):

[image]

Current Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../helper/globals.dart' as globals;

class ToDoListe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("ToDo's"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        ),
        body: ToDoListWidgetList());
  }
}

class ToDoListWidgetList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ToDoListWidgetListState createState() => _ToDoListWidgetListState();
}

class _ToDoListWidgetListState extends State<ToDoListWidgetList> {
  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  var ref;
  Query _todoQuery;
  StreamSubscription<Event> _onTodosChangedSubscription;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onTodosChangedSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    ref = fb.reference();
    //.then((value) => {log("Einkaufsliste gedownloadet")});
    super.initState();

    //_userList = new List();
    _todoQuery = fb.reference().child("users").limitToFirst(10);
    _onTodosChangedSubscription =
        _todoQuery.onChildChanged.listen(onEntryChanged);
  }

  onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    //var oldEntry = _todoList.singleWhere((entry) {
    //  return entry.key == event.snapshot.key;
    //});
    print("TodoChanged_Val: " + event.snapshot.value.toString());
    print("TodoChanged_Key: " + event.snapshot.key);
    Map values = Map.from(event.snapshot.value);

    int userId = int.parse(event.snapshot.key);
    setState(() {
      for (var c in globals.users[userId].todos.entries) {
        if (values["todos"].containsKey(c.key)) {
          globals.users[userId].todos[c.key.toString()] =
              values["todos"][c.key];
        }
      }
      //this here works::::????
      //globals.users[int.parse(event.snapshot.key)].todos["saugen"] =
      //    event.snapshot.value["todos"]["saugen"];

      //globals.users[int.parse(event.snapshot.key)].bierzaehler =
      //    event.snapshot.value["bierzähler"];
      //    event.snapshot.value["bierzähler"];
      //_todoList[_todoList.indexOf(oldEntry)] =
      //  Todo.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = List.generate(
        globals.users.length,
        (int i) => Column(children: [
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: (globals.activeUser == i)
                        ? Colors.green
                        : Colors.greenAccent[100],
                    border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.green),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text("Nutzer: ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 19)),
                                    Text(
                                      globals.users[i].name,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 19,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )
                                  ]))
                        ] +
                        List.generate(
                            globals.users[i].todos.length,
                            (int c) => Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                          globals.users[i].todos.keys
                                                  .toList()[c]
                                                  .toString() +
                                              ": ",
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 19)),
                                      Text(
                                        globals.users[i].todos.values
                                            .toList()[c]
                                            .toString(),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 19,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      OutlineButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          child: Row(children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                                          ]))
                                    ])),
                  ))
            ]));
    var copiedList = List.from(list);
    var copiedUserSpot = copiedList[globals.activeUser];
    list[globals.activeUser] = list[0];

    list[0] = copiedUserSpot;
    return new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: list,
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** after some new attempts it currently looks like this:
[image]

However, when adding `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` back in, it looks like this:
[image]

, which imo is odd. I don't understand why things like`mainAxisAlignment` don't seem to work correctly in this case.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each entry in horizontal listview

```
IntrinsicWidth
-->Column
---->Container(header text)
---->Row - spaceBetween
------>Expanded(Text("saugen"))//and other values
------>SizedBox(width:20)//spacing
------>Flexible(Text("9"))//and other values
------>OutlineButton
```

gives me
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Adding this line like shown in this screenshot (link: https://prnt.sc/ztk9xp) throws an Exception ("BoxConstraints forces an infinite width). The green-boxes are still visible, but nothing's inside.

Comment: I am providing the outline of my code to show the exact fix I did and my result.

Comment: This seems to work. Especially IntrinsicWidth did the trick for me. Thank you!

Comment: as suggested by some other user, it is better to use Table widget for this.